# How to default tasty-html output location?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to default my [tasty-html](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-html) output but it doesn't produce any output file at all.

```
import           Test.Tasty                                (defaultIngredients, defaultMainWithIngredients,
                                                        localOption,
                                                        testGroup)
import           Test.Tasty.Runners.Html                   (HtmlPath (..),
                                                        htmlRunner) -- from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-html


main :: IO ()
main = defaultMainWithIngredients ingredients . localOption htmlPath $ testGroup "tests" [myTests]
  where ingredients = htmlRunner : defaultIngredients
    htmlPath = Just $ HtmlPath "dist/test/test.html" -- this line doesn't seem to work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [haddock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.10/docs/Test-Tasty.html#g:3) says,

> Note that ingredient options (number of threads, hide successes etc.) set in this way will not have any effect. This is for modifying per-test options, such as timeout, number of generated tests etc.

You can set the `TASTY_HTML` environment variable, even inside the test process itself if you wish so. See [setEnv](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/setenv-0.1.1.1/docs/System-SetEnv.html).